# Setting listboxes in MS access form - row by row

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-forms

I have a requirement in MS Access where a table is displayed as several rows in the form. I have created one form detail record(several fields) that will repeat for each row in the Table1. Lets say I have five columns in the Table1. Based on Column3 value, I would like to have a list of value for Column4 and Column5 during form_load. I have also created a separate Table2 to establish relationship between Column3, Column4 and Column5. I have set up Event procedure to populate the values using sub function. The challenge I have is, not being able to set up different listbox 'value list' for different rows. Any tips on populationg form fields IMRecomExIns and AmendReasonExIns by processing each row in Table1 would be a great help.

```
Private Sub IMRecomExIns_Click()

Dim CoverType As String
Dim ListRecomm As String
Dim ListAmend As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tablevar As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tablevar = db.OpenRecordset("Table2")

CoverType = "*" & Me.CoverTypeExIns.Value & "*"

ListRecomm = ""
ListAmend = ""

If tablevar.EOF = False And tablevar.BOF = False Then
    tablevar.MoveFirst
    Do Until tablevar.EOF
        If tablevar!CoverType Like CoverType Then
            ListRecomm = tablevar!Recommendation
            ListAmend = tablevar!AmendReason
            tablevar.MoveLast
        End If
        tablevar.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

Me.IMRecomExIns.RowSourceType = "Value list"
Me.IMRecomExIns.RowSource = ListRecomm

Me.AmendReasonExIns.RowSourceType = "Value list"
Me.AmendReasonExIns.RowSource = ListAmend

End Sub
```

1) I have stored all the value list in a single cell. For example tablevar!Recommendation will have all the values for Me.IMRecomExIns.RowSource, which means the output is will look like "Rec1";"Rec2";"Rec3";etc... Same applies for tablevar!AmendReason "AR1";"AR2';"AR3";ETC... Understand this is not the normalized form of storing data. I want to POC to work before building a full solution with normalized tables.
2) Answered earlier.. the rowsource will be set with all the possible values at the first match, so no point in going all the way to the end of the table 
3) CoverTypeExIns is a string, Table 2 have many different possibilities such as "Mortgage Income" and "Family Income", however the Recommendation and Amendreason are same for all "Income" category that comes from Table1. Thats why the wildcard search.

My problem is not with setting the RowSource for a single row, but setting up RowSource for multiple occurrence in of the same   IMRecommmendation and AmendReason in MS Access screen.

Here is the design view of the form. This form is linked to MS Access table. For multiple rows the Detail record will repeat itself as many times.
[image: MS Access Form Design]

An example of two rows displayed in the screen. 
[image: Form Display view]

Comment: I can't see any Listboxes! Seems like you mixed them with ComboBoxes! You issue i caused by access cheating on continuous form details view, as there is only one control (otherwise the would have different names) copied multiple times (for perfance reasons). If you manipulate the controls rowsource in one row, it changes the same in all other displayed rows, so you have to update every time you change row (`Form_Current`event).

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. So, can i update the combobox 'value list' to different values if i set the Form_Current_event ? My bad. yes its a combobox :). I have been switching between combo and list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking/trying to do here.

I can see at several problems with the code that you have:

- You are using `tablevar.MoveLast` in the loop, whic would automatically take you to the end of the recordset.
- Also, you are not concatenating (joining together) `ListRecomm`/`ListAmend`, you are just setting them equal to a value, so each loop that matches will overwrite any previous value.
- Finally, I am not sure what you are doing with trying to find `CoverTypeExIns` - you are using `LIKE`, which would indicate that it is text, but not wrapping the value in single quotes. If it is a numeric value, then you should be using "=".

However, rather than opening a recordset, looping it and checking for a match to build up a list of values, it is better to just set the RowSource of listboxes equal to a SQL string (effectively a query).

Something like (assuming CoverType is numeric):

```
Private Sub IMRecomExIns_Click()
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "SELECT Recommendation FROM Table2 WHERE CoverType=" & Me!CoverTypeExIns
   Me!AmendReasonExIns.RowSource = strSQL
End Sub
```

I prefer to declare a string to hold the SQL statement rather than setting the `.RowSource` directly, as it makes troubleshooting easier.

Regards,

Comment: Agree the data is not normalized yet. But, I would like atleast to POC to work before normalizing all the data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the new information given, below is some VBA code that opens up a recordset based on the information entered in "Cover", and then sets the `.RowSource` property of the two combo boxes to be the value lists. In my example, don't bother setting the `.RowSourceType`, as this should be done at design time:

```
Private Sub IMRecomExIns_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT Recommendation, AmendReason FROM Table2 WHERE CoverType LIKE '*" & Me!cboCover & "*';"
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
        Me!IMRecomExIns.RowSource = rsData!Recommendation
        Me!AmendReasonExIns.RowSource = rsData!AmendReason
    End If
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

As I have previously stated, you should really normalize the design of your database **now**, rather than getting in so far that it requires a major re-write.

Regards,